# Kafka producer JSON value with Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm trying to produce a JSON message to the Kafka topic but the value is always empty when I consume the message.
There are similar questions already but none of them solved my problem.

What I tried is the following:

I have a dictionary:

```
json = {}
json['key'] = "something"
```

I have a producer which works fine (sending empty values):

```
self._producer = Producer(conf)
```

and then I produce the message to Kafka:

```
self._producer.produce(self._output_topic, record_key, json.dumps(json).encode('utf-8'))
```

My topic has a format of `(key=string, value=JSON)`.

The problem is that all the messages have empty value.

Comment: Which library do you use? i use kafka-python and the class for the producer is KafkaProducer, not Producer.

Comment: @novaXire I use the following: from confluent_kafka import Producer

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I need to do the following(key= and value=):

```
self._producer.produce(self._output_topic, key=record_key, value=json.dumps(json))
```

and I removed `.encode('utf-8')` as it is not needed